# ¿Cómo usar correctamente expresión regular en RegExp.prototype.test()?

Tags: javascript, angular, regex

Tengo la siguiente expresión que uso para validación de formularios con Validators y funciona bien.

> ```
> let regex = new RegExp('[A-Za-z0-9À-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1 ]*')
> ```

Sin embargo cuando la uso con test() de RegExp me retorna true a pesar de tener caracteres que no están dentro de la expresión.

Ejemplo

```
let str = "$$"
let regex = new RegExp('[A-Za-z0-9À-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1 ]*')
regex.test(str) --> return true
```

No sé que ocurre. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Tu expresión regular tiene 2 caracteres redundantes: `\u00F1` y `\u00D1` son los caracteres `ñ` y `Ñ` respectivamente, la redundancia es que los mismos se encuentran incluidos en el rango definido por `À-ÿ`. Eso para empezar.

Comment: @MauricioContreras no lo sabia, mil gracias!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eso es porque usas asterisco (*) al final, este indica "cero o mas",  al no haber ningun caracter entra en 0 por ende es verdadero.

Cambialo por un más (+) , con este indicas "uno o mas"

Tambien considera que estas pidiendo una busqueda en la cadena no importa donde pero tiene que existir uno caracteres indicados, si lo que buscas es que SOLO acepte esos caracteres debes indicar que debe ser desde el inicio hasta el final de la cadena

```js
let str = "$$"
let regex = new RegExp('[A-Za-z0-9À-ÿ\\u00f1\\u00d1 ]+');
let regex2 = new RegExp('^[A-Za-z0-9À-ÿ\\u00f1\\u00d1 ]+$');
console.log('regex', regex.test(str));
console.log('regex', regex.test('hola % demo'));
console.log('regex', regex2.test('hola %demo'));
console.log('regex', regex2.test('holademo'));
```

Answer (score 2):

El modificador `*` hace que devuelva verdadero si se encuentran `cero` o más caracteres de los especificados, entonces, prácticamente siempre devolverá `true`.

Cambia por `+` para forzar que siempre exista al menos 1 caracter de la lista:

```js
    let str = "$$";
    let regex = new RegExp('[A-Za-z0-9À-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1 ]+');
    console.log(regex.test(str)); // --> return false
```